# $_SESSION name not defined

Tags: php, html, ajax

This is translated, I'm sorry if there's something wrong.

I have a problem and it is that when I insert the name of the session it tells me that it is undefined. I did tests inserting the manual username and if everything works.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgeB3.jpg

```
<? php
session_start ();
echo var_dump ($ _SESSION);
?>
```

The first thing that the php has is this, as you can see the var_dump correctly shows the user's name.

The message of (username) is not defined in the console.

I'm doing it with a modal.

The textbox is inserted correctly, I just need the name of the session that inserts it. The database works correctly (I tried inserting the parameters manually)

As you can see with var_dump correctly shows the user name of the session. Also insert the content of textarea well, just need to insert the name of the session

```
        <script>
        $(inicializarEventos);
        function inicializarEventos(){
            $("#insertar").click(insertarSugerencia);
        }
        function insertarSugerencia(){
          var nombreUsuario= <?php echo  $_SESSION['usuario']?>;
          var textoSugerencia=$("#textoSugerencia").val();
          console.log(nombreUsuario,textoSugerencia);
          $.ajax({
            url:"bd/bd.php",
            method: "POST",
                                                                                            data:{nombreUsuario:nombreUsuario,textoSugerencia:textoSugerencia},
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(){
          alert ("Sugerencia enviada correctamente");
          $("#modal1").modal("hide");
          }
           });
           }

        </script>
```

Comment: use `session_start();` where ajax located i think

Comment: You'll need to add quotes around the php block, since it won't quote it for you in the javascript block.

Comment: `echo var_dump ($ _SESSION);` is definitely not correct.

Comment: `var nombreUsuario= <?php echo  json_encode($_SESSION['usuario'])?>;` would be safer than your accepted answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to put the contents of your variable between quote as it is a string:

```
var nombreUsuario= "<?php echo  $_SESSION['usuario']?>";
```